# Check if a string is available in a bigger string of length 100,000

Tags: java, c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the fastest substring search algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183582/what-is-the-fastest-substring-search-algorithm)

How do I check if a string is present in a bigger string of length of 100,000 characters in C++ or Java?

I know a method `str.find("sub_string");` but it can't  handle such a big string. 
The max execution time is 1 sec.

Also the sub strings I need to look for can be 50,000!

Comment: Which do you want? C++ or Java or both? The answers will be different for each.

Comment: There is no way you can expect any algorithm to perform in under one second to do this. Execution time must be somewhere in O(n) to O(n^2), or worse.

Comment: Wondering where do you find a string of 100,000 length and of what use?

Comment: Why is this an SO question? Just write code that does what you need using whatever [string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) you like. As asked, this is way too vague to answer because it doesn't give us nearly enough information to choose the appropriate algorithm. (Does the substring change from search to search? Does the string? Is the string evenly distributed characters? Does the substring contain rare inner substrings? And so on.)

Comment: c++ or java...any of them will work...

Comment: @Drise It's definitely `O(n)`. But 100,000 should be doable in under 1 sec regardless.

Comment: Dear god, char*. Are you kidding?

Comment: I did some timings, see my answer, 4ms...

Comment: @Mysticial: Actually (using one of the Boyer-Moore variants, for example) this can be sub-linear (e.g., in best case, the number of comparisons is N/M, where N is length of haystack and M is length of needle).

Comment: also my test cases can be 50,000!! what should i do in such case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This completes almost instantly (4ms) on my modest 1st gen Intel iMac. I put the search string between two blocks of 100,000 characters in case java searches backwards.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    builder.append((char) i);
}
builder.append("sub_string");
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    builder.append((char) i);
}
String maxString = builder.toString();
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(maxString.contains("sub_string"));
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(t2 - t1);
```

Output

```
true
4
```

Answer (score 5):

In C or C++, you can just use `malloc` to get a chunk of 100,000 bytes. Fill it with your data. To find a needle in a haystack, you can use the following code:

```
void *mem_mem(void *haystack, int haystack_len, void *needle, int needle_len)
{
  const char *begin;
  const char *const last_possible
    = (const char *) haystack + haystack_len - needle_len;

  if (needle_len == 0)
    return (void *) &((const char *) haystack)[needle_len - 1];

  for (begin = (const char *) haystack; begin <= last_possible; ++begin)
    if (begin[0] == ((const char *) needle)[0] &&
    !memcmp ((const void *) &begin[1],
         (const void *) ((const char *) needle + 1),
         needle_len - 1))
      return (void *) begin;

  return NULL;
}
```

On any reasonably modern platform, this will find any substring in 100,000 bytes in a tiny fraction of a second. You can modify it to use `char *` types trivially. If you do multiple searches in the same haystack, try to only compute the haystack length once. Don't call `strlen` when you don't need to.

This will be horribly sub-optimal if your haystack contains many repetitions of the first character or characters of your needle. For example, searching for "ab" in "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaqaaaa.." (or worse, "abc" in "abababababababab...abc...") will be slow. But you didn't give nearly enough details for us to determine the optimum implementation.

It's entirely possible that the point of the question is to write the algorithm with the best possible worst case performance. If so, this is probably not the "right" answer. One can imagine a haystack of all a's followed by a single b at the end and a needle consisting of all a's followed by a single b at the end. In that case, this algorithm might need a very long time.

Comment: For one terrible question, I think this is the most reasonable answer, especially the repeated characters bit.

Comment: I suspect an online judge, so the test cases would probably include something like `needle = a^9999b, haystack=a^100000` which would not be doable within the time limit with the naive algorithm.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good point. It's entirely possible that the point of the question is to write the algorithm with the best possible worst case performance. If so, this is probably not the "right" answer.

Comment: You should incorporate [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536157/check-if-a-string-is-available-in-a-bigger-string-of-length-100-000#comment16879474_12536157) into the answer to cover that case too :D

Comment: @DanielFischer: You're right. Done.

Comment: also my test cases can be 50,000!! what should i do in such case?

Comment: @r20rock: Can be 50,000 what?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming java:

```
String.contains("stringtofind");
```

Is one way to find if string exists with in another string, [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Comment: @r20rock: I didn't test it with big string. But, javadoc didn't specify any limits, so it should work.

Comment: Adding more ? does not help you get answers faster or better. Just makes me want to troll you hard.

Comment: keep in mind that..string.contains() is case sensitive check

Answer (score 1):

In java three way to find String content.

```
String.contains("charSequence");
String.contentEquals("charSequence");
String.contentEquals("StringBuffer");
```

And you are be able to get max a String of length `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (always `2147483647 (2^31 - 1)`) by the Java specification.