# How can I efficiently find all people mentioned in some text, while tolerating spelling mistakes?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search, aho-corasick

I have a list of names of millions of famous people (from Wikidata), and I need to create a system that efficiently finds all people mentioned in a fairly short text: it can be just one word (eg. "Einstein") to a few pages of text (eg. a Wikipedia page).

I need the system to be fairly tolerant to spelling mistakes (eg. Mikael Jackson instead of Michael Jackson), and short forms (eg. M. Jackson). In case of ambiguity, it should return all possible people (eg. "George Bush" should return both father and son, and possibly other homonyms).

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690446/finding-all-matches-from-a-large-set-of-strings-in-a-smaller-string) has a few interesting answers, including using the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm). There are libraries in many languages, including [in Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick/). However, it does not seem to support fuzzy search (ie. tolerate misspellings).

I guess I could extend the vocabulary to include all the possible spellings of each name, but that would make the vocabulary too large, so I would rather avoid that if possible (moreover, I may want to extend this solution to more than just people at one point).

I took a quick look at [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/)/ElasticSearch but it does not seem to support this use case (unless I missed it).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch has support for fuzzy matching: See documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_fuzziness).