# C finding the shortest substring of the string s1 that contains all letters from s2

Tags: c, string, substring

The user inputs the strings `s1` and `s2`. Find the smallest substring of the string `s1` that contains all the letters of `s2`. (if there are more than one of equal size, find the first one that appears)

Example input:

```
it is raining today
dot
```

Output: `tod`

Note: I wrote a working code, but it took me too much time to figure out and write, and since I'll have such examples on a test, that isn't good. **Is there a simpler way?**

How I did it: I wrote two functions, one that returns a substring from index `i` to index `j` for a given string, and another to check whether the substring contains all letters. Then I used them to find the shortest substring that contains all the letters by using nested for loops.

My code (working):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

const int LEN = 100;

char *subString(int beg, int end, int n, char str[n])
{
    int resultLen = abs(end - beg), i;
    char *result = malloc(sizeof(char) * resultLen);

    for (i = 0; i < resultLen; i++)
    {
        result[i] = str[i + beg - 1];
    }

    return result;
}

int doesSubstrContainAllLetters(int substrLen, int lettersLen, char substr[substrLen], char letters[lettersLen])
{
    int i, j, result = 1;
    char *containtChar;

    for (i = 0; i < lettersLen; i++)
    {
        containtChar = strchr(substr, letters[i]);

        if (containtChar == 0)
        {
            result = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            *containtChar = '+';
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char s1[LEN], s2[LEN];

    gets(s1);
    gets(s2);

    int s1Len = strlen(s1);
    int s2Len = strlen(s2);
    int res, min_substrLen = INT_MAX, substrLen, i, j, c;

    for (i = 0; i < s1Len - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < s1Len; j++)
        {

            char *substr = subString(i, j, s1Len, s1);
            substrLen = strlen(substr);

            res = doesSubstrContainAllLetters(strlen(substr), s2Len, substr, s2);

            if (res == 1)
            {
                min_substrLen = (substrLen < min_substrLen) ? substrLen : min_substrLen;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < s1Len - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < s1Len; j++)
        {
            char *substr = subString(i, j, s1Len, s1);
            substrLen = strlen(substr);

            res = doesSubstrContainAllLetters(strlen(substr), s2Len, substr, s2);

            if (res == 1 && substrLen == min_substrLen)
            {
                char *substr = subString(i, j, s1Len, s1);
                printf("%s", substr);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From an experienced programmer: this is not a trivial task, and it is probably ok to take some hours, depending on your level. I actually know some 'senior programmers' that wouldn't be able to complete it error-free. How long did you take?

Comment: It took me 1 hour to the minute Edit: but afaik what I wrote was very inefficient code, but I don't actually care about that on a test, only the time it takes to write

Comment: My question is more of a "is there a function in C that does most of the job for me" or something.

Comment: Improvement of working code is very much on-topic at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that existed.

Comment: If _needle_ was `"dott"`, should the _haystack_ need 1 or 2 `t`?

Comment: Fast substring search is a big part of computer science and regular expressions. Read about Boyer Moore. And others! Maybe read https://stackoverflow.com/a/3183711/13422

Comment: Although I just noticed that your "needle" can appear in any order which makes it different.

Comment: No, there isn't a function that does most of the job for you. A different approach to the problem is to use a histogram, and a sliding window.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: from the OP's code, if `s2` contains repeated characters, the substring from `s1` must also have them repeated to be a match. This may not be the actual specification, but that's what the implementation does.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some shortcomings:

- you should not use `gets()`.
- you allocate a lot memory and never free it.
- it does not work as expected if `s2` contains one or more `+` characters

There is no function in the C library that does something close to what you need.

The problem is not so easy to solve, it took me 40 minutes to get an implementation that I believe is sturdy, albeit not very fast. It does not allocate memory, but assumes bytes have 8 bits.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *minsubstr(const char *str, const char *set, size_t *plen) {
    size_t count[256] = { 0 }, cc[256];
    size_t i, n, set_len, best_len = -1;
    const char *best = NULL;
    for (i = 0; set[i]; i++) {
        unsigned char c = set[i];
        count[c]++;
    }
    set_len = i;
    if (set_len == 0) {
        best_len = 0;
        best = str;
    } else {
        for (; *str; str++) {
            if (count[(unsigned char)*str] == 0)
                continue;
            memcpy(cc, count, sizeof cc);
            for (i = n = 0; i < best_len && str[i]; i++) {
                unsigned char c = str[i];
                if (cc[c]) {
                    cc[c]--;
                    if (++n == set_len) {
                        if (best_len > i + 1) {
                            best_len = i + 1;
                            best = str;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!str[i]) {
                // no more matches
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    *plen = best_len;
    return best;
}

int main() {
    char s1[100], s2[100];
    const char *p;
    size_t len;

    if (fgets(s1, sizeof s1, stdin) && fgets(s2, sizeof s2, stdin)) {
        s1[strcspn(s1, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the trailing newline
        s2[strcspn(s2, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the trailing newline if any
        p = minsubstr(s1, s2, &len);
        if (p) {
            printf("%.*s\n", (int)len, p);
        } else {
            printf("no match\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an alternative approach that does allocate some memory but should be faster for small `s2` strings:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *minsubstr(const char *str, const char *set, size_t *plen) {
    size_t i, len, set_len = strlen(set), best_len = -1;
    const char *best = NULL;
    if (set_len == 0) {
        best_len = 0;
        best = str;
    } else {
        char *buf = malloc(set_len);
        for (; *str; str++) {
            if (!memchr(set, *str, set_len))
                continue;
            memcpy(buf, set, len = set_len);
            for (i = 0; i < best_len && str[i]; i++) {
                char *p = memchr(buf, str[i], len);
                if (p != NULL) {
                    *p = buf[--len];
                    if (len == 0) {
                        if (best_len > i + 1) {
                            best_len = i + 1;
                            best = str;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!str[i]) {
                // no more matches
                break;
            }
        }
        free(buf);
    }
    *plen = best_len;
    return best;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll analyze and learn from your code. I was aware of some of the shortcomings but I didn't really have time or care about them given the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses histograms and a sliding window to find the best match. It assumes that only lower case letters are of interest. The histograms can be expanded to cover a different character set, if desired. It has no memory allocation, and runs in O(n) time. The first draft, which correctly identified `"tod"` as the correct output for the needle `"dot"` took me 31 minutes to write, including debug time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char *findMinSubstring(char *haystack, char *needle, int *bestLength)
{
    int needleHistogram[26] = {0};
    int haystackHistogram[26] = {0};

    // create a histogram from the needle, keeping track of the number of non-zero entries in the histogram
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; needle[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (islower(needle[i]))
        {
            int c = needle[i] - 'a';
            needleHistogram[c]++;
            if (needleHistogram[c] == 1)
                count++;
        }

    // now look for the best substring using a sliding window
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int length = (int)strlen(haystack);
    int bestStart = -1;
    int bestEnd = length+1;
    for (;;)
    {
        if (end < length && count != 0)
        {
            // if the window doesn't contain all of the necessary letters, enlarge it by advancing the end
            if (islower(haystack[end]))
            {
                int c = haystack[end] - 'a';
                haystackHistogram[c]++;
                if (needleHistogram[c] > 0 && haystackHistogram[c] == needleHistogram[c])
                    count--;
            }
            end++;
        }
        else if (start < end && count == 0)
        {
            // if the window contains all of the necessary letters, shrink it by advancing the start
            if (islower(haystack[start]))
            {
                int c = haystack[start] - 'a';
                haystackHistogram[c]--;
                if (needleHistogram[c] > 0 && haystackHistogram[c] == needleHistogram[c]-1)
                    count++;
            }
            start++;
        }
        else
        {
            // if expanding or shrinking the window isn't an option, then we're done
            break;
        }

        // if the window contains all the necessary letters, and is smaller than the previous best, update the best
        if (count == 0 && (end - start) < (bestEnd - bestStart))
        {
            bestStart = start;
            bestEnd = end;
        }
    }

    if (bestStart >= 0 && bestEnd <= length)
    {
        // if a matching substring exists, return the length and a pointer to the beginning of the substring
        *bestLength = bestEnd - bestStart;
        return haystack + bestStart;
    }
    else
    {
        // failed, return NULL
        *bestLength = 0;
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char haystack[] = "it is raining today";
    char *needle[] = { "dot", "dott", "dotti", "it", "today", "i", "ii", "iii", "iiii", "iiiii", "y", "yy", "end", NULL };
    for (int i = 0; needle[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        int bestLength = 0;
        char *bestString = findMinSubstring(haystack, needle[i], &bestLength);
        printf("%-5s ", needle[i]);
        if (bestString != NULL)
            printf("'%.*s'\n", bestLength, bestString);
        else
            printf(" No matching substring\n");
    }
}
```

`main` has a variety of test cases, including the test case from the question. The output from the program is:

```
dot   'tod'
dott  't is raining tod'
dotti 't is raining tod'
it    'it'
today 'today'
i     'i'
ii    'ini'
iii   'is raini'
iiii  'it is raini'
iiiii  No matching substring
y     'y'
yy     No matching substring
end    No matching substring
```

Comment: Nicely done.   Rather than a lower case histogram, could simple use a `size_t needleHistogram[UCHAR_MAX+1]`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps avoid nested `for` loops and the `O(n^2)` time that those cost, by using sorted strings:

1. Lexicographically sort `s2` (call this sorted string: `s2S`).
2. Tokenize `s1` by splitting on whitespace.
3. Loop through tokens from `s1`.
4. Keep the original token (`s1T`) and a lexicographically-sorted version of the same token (`s1S`).
5. Look through `s1S` for a copy of `s2S`.
6. If there is a match, then you have a substring in `s1T` that contains the characters of `s2`.
7. Loop through each letter of `s1T`, until you find one of the starting characters in `s2S`. Compare the next character, and so on, until you have a substring or a mismatch. If all characters match, you have a candidate hit.

This reduces your time from your `O(n^2)` to `O(nlogn)`, when using sorted strings. Looping through characters in strings is `O(n)`.