# Brute force pattern algorithm

Tags: python, matching, brute-force

Using Python, how would you implement a brute-force string matching algorithm? It should find a pattern (string of m characters) in a text (string of n characters). Verify your code with outputs from following test cases:

```
Test case#1:
Text: 10110100110010111
Pattern: 001011

Test case#2:
Text: It is never too late to have a happy childhood
Pattern: happier

Test case#3:
Text: NOBODY_NOTICED_HIM 
Pattern: NOT
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Questions like this are not suitable for Stack Overflow. Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/) for relevant guidance (since the question is almost two years old, there is not much point in directing this specifically at OP). There are multiple reasonable questions that could be uncovered here, but they are all duplicates: e.g. the question about how to do it pragmatically (rather than writing it yourself) is [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/).

Comment: For a general overview of proper string searching algorithms, see e.g. [What is the fastest substring search algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183582) Such a question is only on topic insofar as it's language-agnostic; we don't write code to specification here. A Python-specific question would need to be about a single, specific aspect of the code, e.g. a problem that came up while trying to implement such an algorithm.

Comment: If the intended question is simply about how to take a naive approach, then there are several obvious logical steps to that: e.g. check whether a substring of the "haystack" is equal to the "needle", and repeat that process for each equal-length substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
pattern in text
```

for this. If you need to implement the entire algorithm from scratch it's also rather easy:

```
def contains(text, pattern):
    for i in range(len(text)):
        for j in range(len(pattern)):
            if i + j >= len(text):
                break
            if text[i + j] != pattern[j]:
                break
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

Usage

```
contains('10110100110010111', '001011') # True
contains('It is never too late to have a happy childhood', 'happier') # False
```

It should be noted that there are other algorithms that are going to be much more efficient, for example the famous [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).